# How do you detect and delete infinite values from a time series in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, infinite

I can't calculate the mean of a variable because it has infinite values in it, but I can't find and fix them:

```
perc_df[['variable']].mean()

variable    inf
dtype: float64
```

I've never dealt with infinite values before, is there an equivalent to "isna()" and "dropna()" for infinite values in pandas?
If there isn't, how do I deal with these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to filter out the infinite values with [`numpy.inf`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/constants.html#numpy.Inf). The code is following:

```
import numpy as np
perc_df[perc_df.variable != np.inf].variable.mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you:

```
perc_df = perc_df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```